# Reading SD cards on a GPO blocked USB

Tags: usb, sd-card, gpo

Our company has a GPO which blocks USB mass storage devices. The GPO permits Media Transfer Protocol (MTP) connections. Some SD card-based camera devices don't support MTP so they are blocked as they identify as a mass storage device. I can remove the SD card, but is there an SD card reader available that can use MTP?

Comment: Although you asked as a security concern, the question itself is not about security. You either need a pointer to a product (off-topic) or you need to configure other hardware to do what you need (also off-topic).

Answer (score 1):

I am unaware of an MTP SD Card reader, and cannot find anything listing the USB reader having this support. So, instead, I would suggest using an Android device, which has micro SD card support, as Android supports MTP. [USB mass storage instead of MTP](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155819/usb-mass-storage-instead-of-mtp) outlines doing the opposite of what you want but gives an idea of how you can use Android 5.0 to mount a micro SD card in MTP mode.